# How is the atmospheric composition of objects in the Solar System measured?

Tags: astronomy, atmospheric-science, spectroscopy, solar-system

How is the atmospheric composition of astronomical objects, for example Triton, a moon of Neptune, determined?

Comment: This would have been just as good--or [perhaps a bit better](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/725/520)--on on [Astronomy.SE](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) (no pressure, I won't migrate it to a beta site without your say-so). I'll migrate if you want, or it can stay here (but please don't [cross-post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/888/520)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They check for absorption lines when conditions are appropriate. Have a look at this [ozone layer in Venus' atmosphere  detected by ESA.](http://www.esa.int/export/esaSC/SEMU3N9U7TG_index_0.html)